# PDF reader with search history for Windows

Tags: windows, pdf, pdf-viewer, search, history

Looking for a PDF reader with search history (say 100 last items) for Windows.

Both commercial and freeware recommendations are welcome.

Comment: Heared, that Foxit Reader shuld have such feature, but since it´s comercial software never tried it.

Comment: Installed. Don't see where is it. There is no drop-down list with the prev. searching text.  Tried both simple search and advanced search. Idea: add this feature yourself to any open source PDF reader.

Comment: Sorry, like mentioned never using commercial software, so have no own experience.

Answer (score 0):

[PDF-XChange Editor](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor) by Tracker Software (horrible name, I know... but great software!) is a quality Windows PDF reader that has search history.

I have personally used this software, and I consider it to be excellent.  The only big thing it's currently missing is a good dark mode.